# Merge "Citations" and "bibliography" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Is there a distinction between the [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) and [bibliography](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibliography) tags? Both refer to either citing something or adding it to the bibliography, which are essentially one task (everything cited is added to the bibliography). Are there any counter-examples or edge cases I missed? Can these be merged?

Answer (score 1):

The citations tag is written up as

> Queries related to citing or referencing published or unpublished sources.

used for questions about citing and citations, not necessarily in th econtext of a bibliography (reference list). The Bibliography tag says

> Questions related to the structure, building and typesetting of a bibliography comes under this tag. Bibliography is an organized

So both are useful as I see it. I think that the citations tag may be used wrong and so there is probably reasons for checking tagging more carefully. There are also quite a few tag wikis that are not written up which may contribute to confuion since it is unclear what they represent.