# Tag Synonym Request [citations] [references]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Should [references](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references), 51 questions, no tag wiki,
and [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) 151 questions, with a tag wiki,
be merged?

There is a overlap of 13 posts.

See also [Merge “Citations” and “bibliography” tags?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/merge-citations-and-bibliography-tags)

Answer (score 4):

The problem I see with [references](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) is some users think it refers to citations and others think it refers to reference letters. I think we probably need to decide which one is which, retag the questions that do not belong, and add a tag wiki and synonym. It might be best to come up with a list and let the diamond mods do a mass retag to avoid flooding the front page.

I think tagging is one area we are weak on. I have a bunch of proposed synonyms that have just been sitting in voted on. Some I am not sure about, but others are pretty obvious in my mind.